# Ubuntu 18.04 suspend hardblocking wifi card

Tags: linux, ubuntu, wireless-networking, suspend

I am using ubuntu 18.04 on a dual booted HP Pavilion Notebook -17-g005nx (ENERGY STAR). (ubuntu/windows 10) UEFI with secure boot disabled.

The wifi card is BCM43142

```
08:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [14e4:4365] (rev 01)
           Subsystem:Hewlett-Packard Company BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [103c:804a]
           Kernelmodules: bcma, wl
```

Upon bootup from OFF state, the wifi works properly. However, after wakingup from a suspend

```
user@computer:~$ rfkill list all
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: brcmwl-0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: yes
2: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

**Things I've tried**

1) Reseting wl module

```
user@computer:~$ sudo modprobe -r bcma
user@computer:~$ sudo modprobe bcma
user@computer:~$ sudo modprobe -r wl
user@computer:~$ sudo modprobe wl
```

2) Suspending wl module

```
user@computer:~$ cat /etc/pm/config.d/config
SUSPEND_MODULES="wl"
```

**Note:** the config file is owned by root and is executable. I also tried placing the file in `/etc/pm/sleep.d/`

3) BIOS Settings

- Tried enabling secure boot
- Tried redisabling secure boot
- Tried enabled boot internal networking
- Tried disabling fn key requirement (I thought maybe the airplane mode key has to do something)
- Tried factory settings

**Nothing I've tried so far seems to work.** What can I furthermore do?

**P.S.:** Originally I wanted hibernation to work, but that seemed like a dead end so I settled down for sleep. Which works find except the wifi gets hardblocked.

**Update 1**
The airplone mode fn key was not working while other fn keys where working just fine. So I tried switching to ttyl and it worked there, only it didn't solve the problem. Enabling it would put a softblock on the wifi card and disabling it would just lift the softblock without effecting the hardblock.

Comment: Maybe the suspension triggers the WiFi switch. Doesn't it turn on if you use it?

Comment: If by WiFi switch you mean the airplane mode key on the keyboard. It really does nothing. Neither does it disable it when its running, nor does it enable it when its disabled. I think ubuntu doesn't really recognize it somehow. Other fn keys like volume, brightness, etc. seem to work fine though.

Comment: Yes, that was what I meant. :(